# Angular show sign out after sign up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular authentication with `ng-token-auth`. Its not showing **Sign Out** button, after **Sign Up**. But it works for **Sign In**.

I am not redirecting it anywhere. Also, `isLoggedIn(), signOut()` functions work fine.

Where exactly am i doing wrong ? Thank You !

**Navbar Controller**

```
function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $auth, currentUser) {

  $scope.isLoggedIn = function() {
    return ($scope.user.id) ? true : false;
  }

  $scope.signOut = function() {
    currentUser.signOut();
  };
```

**Auth Controller**

```
  $scope.submitRegistration = function() {
    $auth.submitRegistration($scope.registrationForm)
      .then(function(res) {
        currentUser.set(res.data.data);
        $scope.close();
      })
      .catch(function(res) {
        $scope.errors = res.data.errors.full_messages.join(', ');
      })
  };

  $scope.submitLogin = function() {
    $auth.submitLogin($scope.loginForm)
      .then(function(resp) {
        currentUser.set(resp);
        $scope.close();
      })
      .catch(function(resp) {
         $scope.errors = "Email or Password invalid...";
      });
  };
```

**Navbar HTML**

```
    <li ng-controller="AuthModalCtrl" ng-if='!isLoggedIn()'>
      <div ng-click="openModal(signin)">Sign In</div>
    </li>
    <li ng-controller="AuthModalCtrl" ng-if='!isLoggedIn()'>
        <div class="bubble-btn sign-up" ng-click="openModal('register')">Sign Up</div>
    </li>
    <li ng-controller="NavCtrl" ng-show='isLoggedIn()'>
       <div ng-click="signOut()">Sign Out</div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, users are able to log in correctly but you want to log them in automatically after they register.

According to the [ng-token-auth documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-token-auth#authsubmitregistration), **$auth.submitRegistration** doesn't log the user in automatically, it only registers the user. You would need to explicitly log the user in in the success callback from submitRegistration.

It looks like the [success callback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-token-auth#authregistration-email-success) gives you a response that has the parameters that you sent with the registration. You would need to do something like this:

```
$scope.submitRegistration = function() {
    $auth.submitRegistration($scope.registrationForm)
      .then(function(res) {

        //todo: use res to build out your login object

        // You could either call the ng-token-auth function submitLogin           
        // here and provide another callback, or you could call your 
        // $scope.submitLogin and leverage that existing functionality
        $auth.submitLogin( ...submit your login params... )

        $scope.close();
      })
      .catch(function(res) {
        $scope.errors = res.data.errors.full_messages.join(', ');
      })
  };
```

Comment: nice catch, Ill check it.